# java.nio.channels.OverlappingFileLockException occurring randomly when attempting to embed applet?

Tags: java, exception, applet

Has anyone ever seen this odd error when attempting to load an applet? I get this in jconsole, although the applet activity is pretty plain. I get this exception after

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.plugin.AppletViewer.loadJarFiles(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a 1.6.13 issue. It was a JRE bug.